# R substr on two lists

Tags: r, loops, substring

I have two lists.  The first has strings for each element.  The second list has a data frame for each element.  The data frames have a column "start" and another "end", along with other info.

```
text<-'this is a long text.  its not an email'
text0<-'another piece of text'
text1<-'last sentence of nonsense'
all.text<-list(text,text0,text1)
features1<-data.frame(start=c(1,3,5,7),end=c(2,5,9,12),type=c('na','person','person','location'))
features2<-data.frame(start=c(1,3,5,7),end=c(2,5,9,12),type=c('na','person','person','location'))
features3<-data.frame(start=c(7,8,10,12),end=c(9,9,11,15),type=c('na','person','person','location'))
all.features<-list(features1,features2, features3)
```

I hope to cycle the first text element and the first data frame.  The data frame's columns start and end can be used within substr to extract the text.

For an individual text element I can use the loop below then add it to the features data frame.

```
one.text<-NULL 
for (i in 1:nrow(features1)) one.text[i]<-((substr(text,features1[i,1],features1[i,2])))
features1$word<-one.text
```

However I can't find a way to use lapply or to nest a loop.  Obviously I don't want to use a loop if possibly because I read they are inefficient.  Some of the things I have tried:

```
named.get<-function(text.list,features.list){
  named.entities<-substr(text.list,features.list[,1],features.list[,2])
}
all<-sapply(all.text,named.get,all.features)
```

Or a nested loop

```
one.obj<-NULL
two.obj<-NULL
for(i in 1:length(all.text)){
  for (j in 1:length(all.features)){
    one.obj[j]<-list([i]<-((substr(all.text[i],all.features[[i]][j,1],all.features[[i]][j,2]))))
  }
}
```

But that didn't work either.  I have read the substr vignette, read multiple stackoverflow questions and can't seem to find a way forward with this.

The objective is to get a the features list with the extracted terms appended to it like I did for the single loop above.  Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of a double-for-loop is to use `Map` with both of the corresponding lists passed as arguments. Then you can take advantage of the fact that `substring` is vectorised to do the final extraction.

```
Map(function(tex,fea) substring(tex, fea$start, fea$end), all.text, all.features)
#[[1]]
#[1] "th"     "is "    " is a"  "s a lo"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "an"     "oth"    "her p"  "r piec"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "ent"  "nt"   "en"   "ce o"
```

Comment: For my own curiosity, is this possible to add these output to the corresponding locations? I mean can we add `#[1] "th"     "is "    " is a"  "s a lo"` to `all.features[[1]]` and similarly for others.

Comment: @user2100721 - sure - something like `Map(function(tex,fea) cbind(fea, string=substring(tex, fea$start, fea$end)), all.text, all.features)`